# inspect.getcode on lambda in class decorator returns entire class in PY3

Tags: python, lambda, decorator, inspect, six

We are finally migrating from Python 2.7.13 to Python 3.6.6 and I have found some strange behaviour of inspect.getcode that behaves very differently in Python 3.6.6 compared to Python 2.7.13.

We have a number of classes that have a decorator that defines if an instance of this class is allowed to do a certain operation. This check is done by a separate module that manages these decorators rather than by the class itself.
To avoid unintentional changes, we use unit testing to record the code inside the decorator and compare it against a benchmark. The code is recorded with inspect.getcode().
If the decorator uses an external method, then result captured by PY2 and PY3 is identical - the code of the method.
However, if the decorator uses a lambda expression, the result is quite different:

- PY2 returns the entire decorator, not just the lambda expression, but that's not really a problem for the unit test.
- PY3, however, returns the decorator and the entire class - and this is a problem because now any change in the class would break this unit test.

I could not find any documented difference in inspect.getsource() that would explain this. Am I missing something here or is this a bug? I know that there are easy workarounds, e.g. I could just check the returned string and clip everything below the lambda - but I'd rather understand why this is happening.

Here is some example code that you can directly run in PY2 and PY3 (needs six).
This code is written from scratch to demonstrate the problem - please do not worry about the actual implementation of the decorator or other ways of implementing this.

```
checks = dict()  # a mapping of class to check function

# the class decorator
def check(check_function):
    def wrap(wrapped):
        checks[wrapped] = check_function
        return wrapped
    return wrap

# example 1: check with lambda. This demonstrates the problem
@check(lambda cls: True)
class checked_with_lambda(object):
    def run(self):
        pass

# example 2: check with external helper. This works as expected
def my_checker(obj):
    return True

@check(my_checker)
class checked_with_function(object):
    def run(self):
        pass


# this is how the check would be used. This works fine
c = checked_with_lambda()
if checks[type(c)](c):
    c.run()

# this is what a unit test would do 
# (I have added the looks-like line to show that the check function is actually what I am expecting)
import six, inspect
for cls, check in six.iteritems(checks):
    print('Check for "{}":\n'
          'looks like: "{}"\n'
          'code: "{}"\n'.format(cls.__name__,
                                repr(check),
                                inspect.getsource(check)))
```

If I run this code with Python 2.7.13, this result is as expected:

```
Check for "checked_with_lambda":
looks like: "<function <lambda> at 0x0000025967FB2A58>"
code: "@check(lambda cls: True)
"

Check for "checked_with_function":
looks like: "<function my_checker at 0x0000025967FB2AC8>"
code: "def my_checker(obj):
    return True
"
```

In PY3, this looks quite different - note how the check-function code for the first class includes the entire class code:

```
Check for "checked_with_lambda":
looks like: "<function <lambda> at 0x000002A2B295BC80>"
code: "@check(lambda cls: True)
class checked_with_lambda(object):
    def run(self):
        pass
"

Check for "checked_with_function":
looks like: "<function my_checker at 0x000002A2B295BD08>"
code: "def my_checker(obj):
    return True
"
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT this is a deliberate change in Python 3.  `inspect.getsource` is line based, and in python 3 the `inspect.BlockFinder` helper class detects the line the lambda definition is in is a decorator and returns the whole decorated object.  Python 2 did not do this.
You will just have to work around this.